# How can I merge a .wav file along with a .wmv file?

Tags: merge, wmv, wav

I have the two files separately and I need to merge them so that the sound is synchronized with the video.

How can I merge a .wmv file with a .wav file?

Preferably via a GUI interface.

Comment: [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: This question does not show any research effort. What have you already tried? Does it need to be GUI-based? Does the video have to stay the same encoding? Does the original video file have an audio stream that needs to be replaced?

Comment: I looked at ffmpeg but was unsure of whether there was a GUI based tool to do this

Answer (score 2):

Try using Microsoft Movie Maker on Windows. It's free, and also gives you some more options (like determining if you want emphasis on narration or the background music). After you have downloaded it or located it on your system, click "add videos or photos" and locate the wmv file. Then, click "add music" and locate the proper wav file that you want imported. You can export it as wmv or mp4 by going to file, then save movie.

Answer (score -1):

[Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/) will do the trick and much more.

Comment: Sab is a new user here. Be kind and provide a link as well as a rough description of steps one would need to go through in Audacity to achieve the result.